# How to print in pdf after deployed application

Tags: java

I'm beginner in programming, I'm using eclipse kepler including WindowBuilder I have a problem, in my application, before deployed I print data from database (MySQl) in pdf it's running well but after deployed(using Lauch4j and InnoSetup Compiler) it 's not possible, when I click on print button no reaction! can you help me please?
this is function code I'm using to write in pdf

public void imprimerFacture() throws DocumentException {

```
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
    Date str = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat sdt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String strdat = sdt.format(str);
    Table tableau = new Table(8,2);

    try {

     PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("src/images/facture.pdf"));
     document.open()

    Paragraph phrase = new Paragraph(new Chunk("Le "+strdat,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 10, Font.BOLD, Color.BLUE)).setBackground(Color.yellow));
    phrase.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_TOP);
    phrase.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
    document.add(phrase);

    Paragraph ftitre = new Paragraph("Magasin   :...........",FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 10, Font.BOLD, Color.BLUE));
    //ftitre.setUnderline(2f, -5f);
    ftitre.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_TOP);
    ftitre.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
    document.add(ftitre);

    Paragraph ftitre1 = new Paragraph("Adresse   :...........",FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 10, Font.BOLD, Color.BLUE));
    //ftitre.setUnderline(2f, -5f);
    ftitre1.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_TOP);
    ftitre1.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
    document.add(ftitre1);


    Paragraph ftitre2 = new Paragraph("Téléphone :...........",FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 10, Font.BOLD, Color.BLUE));
    //ftitre.setUnderline(2f, -5f);
    ftitre2.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_TOP);
    ftitre2.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
    document.add(ftitre2);

    Chunk chunk = new Chunk("Commandes disponibles",FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 12, Font.BOLD, Color.BLUE));
            chunk.setUnderline(0.2f,-2f);

            //chunk.ALIGN_CENTER
            document.add(chunk);

        tableau.setAutoFillEmptyCells(true);



    } catch (DocumentException de) {de.printStackTrace();} 
      catch (IOException ioe) {ioe.printStackTrace();}
    try {
        Statement state = Connection_bd.getInstance().createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        ResultSet res = state.executeQuery("select ReferenceCommande,Designation,Quantite,DateLivraison,Categorie,MontantCommande,Date,IdentifiantClient from Commande");
        //ResultSetMetaData meta = res.getMetaData();
        tableau.addCell("ReferenceCommande");
        tableau.addCell("Designation");
        tableau.addCell("Quantite");
        tableau.addCell("DateLivraison");
        tableau.addCell("Categorie");
        tableau.addCell("MontantCommande");
        tableau.addCell("Date");
        tableau.addCell("IdentifiantClient");
        tableau.setWidth(110);

        while(res.next()){


            tableau.addCell(res.getString("ReferenceCommande"));
            tableau.addCell(res.getString("Designation"));
            tableau.addCell(res.getString("Quantite"));
            tableau.addCell(res.getString("DateLivraison"));
            tableau.addCell(res.getString("Categorie"));
            tableau.addCell(res.getString("MontantCommande"));
            tableau.addCell(res.getString("Date"));
            tableau.addCell(res.getString("IdentifiantClient"));



        }  
        document.add(tableau);
        //on ferme le tout                         
        res.close();
        state.close();
        }catch(SQLException e){}
    Paragraph ftitre = new Paragraph("Magasinier",FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER,10,Font.BOLD,Color.BLUE));
    ftitre.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
    document.add(ftitre);
     document.close();
```

}

My function I called in this buttton

btnImprimer_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

```
             int result=JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Voulez-vous réellement imprimer ce(s) commande(s) ?","GE-SHOP1.0 SOFTWARE_MESSAGE",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION); 
                if(result==JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) 
                {
                    String str="select * from commande";
                    String strin=AfficherChaine(str);
                    if(strin.equals(""))
                    { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Cette action ne peut pas aboutir du fait qu'il n'y a rien à imprimer!!!\n Veuillez saisir la(les) nouvelle(es) commande(es) et puis proceder a l'impression !","GE-SHOP1.0 SOFTWARE_MESSAGE",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);}




                else {try {

                //if (listachat.size() > 0){
                      imprimerFacture();


                        if(Desktop.isDesktopSupported()){
                            if(Desktop.getDesktop().isSupported(java.awt.Desktop.Action.OPEN)){
                            try {
                                java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("src/images/facture.pdf"));
                            } catch (IOException ex) {
                                //Traitement de l'exception
                            }
                            catch (IllegalArgumentException e){}
                            } else {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La fonction n'est pas supportée par votre système d'exploitation","GE-SHOP1.0 SOFTWARE_MESSAGE", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                            }
                        }else{
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Desktop pas supportée par votre système d'exploitation", "GE-SHOP1.0 SOFTWARE_MESSAGE", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        }


                } catch (DocumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                  }

                }} 

                else{if(result==JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
                {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "L'operation d'impression vient d'etre annulée", "GE-SHOP1.0 SOFTWARE_MESSAGE", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);}

                }







        }
    });
```

Comment: java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("src/images/facture.pdf")); catch an exception here and see this is the cause.

Comment: You should create some logging structure to know what is going on.

Comment: I meant at least print the exception. If you run as an EXE file then you won't have console to so try to run as runnable jar .

Answer (score 0):

```
java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("src/images/facture.pdf"));
```

I think the problem is here. When you deploy as jar file your resources can't be accessed like that.

You should use getResource. [Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29)

You can try like

```
String path =Yourclass.class.getResource("/images/facture.pdf").getPath();
java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(path));
```

Comment: Hi Makky, when I wrote this code java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().open(path);it's make erros The method open(File)in the type Desktop is not applicable for the arguments(String) what can I do please?

Comment: Hi Makky I'm using the code getting from Joop Eggen now the problem is finished

Answer (score 0):

The path is the problem.

```
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("src/images/facture.pdf"));
```

Better reserve you own directory for read/write data, typically in the user's home.
You could also create a temporary file (see File).

```
File applicationDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home")
    + File.sepator + ".GE-Shop");
applicationDir.mkdirs();
File pdfFile = new File(applicationDir, "facture.pdf");
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(pdfFile));
```

...

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(pdfFile);
```

Comment: Hi Joop Eggen? I wrote this code but no reaction  what can I do please?

Comment: Vous n'oubliez pas `open(pdfFile)`? I have also added the file's usage.

Comment: HI Joop Eggen?Just to say thanks, now it's running well, but I want to ask you in my application I can print using this code but I do not want a dialogue box there is any code to do it? I want, if I click print button automaticaly print invoice without see the dialog box

Comment: this is the code I'm using to printpublic void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    
     if(!booleanScan)
     {
     
    PrintJob job=getToolkit().getPrintJob(fen,"Impression",null);
       if (job != null){
           Graphics g = job.getGraphics();
               if(g != null){
                   ecran.printAll(g);
                   g.dispose();
                        
               }
               job.end();
       }

Comment: There is `Desktop.getDesktop().print(pdfFile)` too. Certainly I would use in the `actionPerformed`: `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`; search for `invokeLater` for the specifics.

Comment: Hi Joop Eggen? can you help me? I have a problem,In my application I can in the frame I can click on browser buton and I attach image from my machine after I can save it with the information of employee in database mysql but when I want to retrieve  the information of emplyee I will not see the image in my desktop pan where is the problem?

Comment: @fofo `JFileChooser.getSelectedFile()` - what is done with the `File`? I have little insight in you runtime environment. I am willing to help, but have no information. Best you look what is done with the file, isn't it?

Comment: this is the code I'm using to retreive image:try{
      String sql=(" Select idemploye,nomemploye,prenomemploye,telephone,carteidentite,date, image from employe where idemploye = \'" +idemploye+"\'");
      Statement state = Connection_bd.getInstance().createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
      ResultSet res = state.executeQuery(sql);
      if(res.next()) {
            byte[]imagedata=res.getBytes("image");//image=nom de la colonne photo
            format=new ImageIcon(imagedata);
            lblNewLabel_2.setIcon(format);
      }

Comment: Looks good, better PreparedStatement. You could save the bytes in a file for testing.

Comment: `PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("... where idemploye=?"); stmt.setString(1, idemploye);`. Couvre apostrophe en idemploye, et empêche SQL injection.

Comment: @fofo sorry that I could not help. Good luck.

Comment: Hi Joop Eggen? I'm putting jasperstudio plugin in eclipse kepler and I get this error "Installing Software has encountered a problem. An error occcurred collecting items to be installed" please help me?

Comment: @fofo see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18608865/eclipse-error-occurred-collecting-items-to-be-installed-installing-jasperstudi

Comment: Hi,please can you help me the function to make FIFO accounting method?I doing my final project to finish my stady, I'm doing an aplication in java that allow to insert data in database mysql,I want the first to put will be the first to go out.

Comment: @fofo sorry cannot do - at the moment 12h working day; not so bad as still moments for stackoverflow.